# Postgres recovery fails with "unexpected GIN leaf action: 0"

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres database service that is not starting due to an error in the automatic recovery. This error is in the postgres log: `FATAL: unexpected GIN leaf action: 0`. There is only one GIN index in the database. Is there any way to ignore this index during recovery or manually edit the wal file? The full log is:

```
2021-06-30 16:09:47.885 -03 [6240] LOG:  database system was interrupted while in recovery at 2021-06-30 10:52:48 -03
2021-06-30 16:09:47.885 -03 [6240] HINT:  This probably means that some data is corrupted and you will have to use the last backup for recovery.
2021-06-30 16:09:51.088 -03 [6240] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
2021-06-30 16:09:51.094 -03 [6240] LOG:  redo starts at 183/2DC10228
2021-06-30 16:09:51.130 -03 [6240] FATAL:  unexpected GIN leaf action: 0
2021-06-30 16:09:51.130 -03 [6240] CONTEXT:  WAL redo at 183/2DD7F350 for Gin/INSERT: isdata: T isleaf: T 206 segments: 0 unknown action 0 ???
2021-06-30 16:09:51.134 -03 [8424] LOG:  startup process (PID 6240) exited with exit code 1
2021-06-30 16:09:51.134 -03 [8424] LOG:  aborting startup due to startup process failure
2021-06-30 16:09:51.144 -03 [8424] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

Comment: No, and you should report that to the pgsql-hackers mailing list.